# What means unqualifiedResLocale in AGP's automatic per-app language support

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I couldn't find information about the term `unqualifiedResLocale` from [Enable automatic per-app language support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#auto-localeconfig) documentation page anywhere. What does it stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default language used when developing your application (also called `ultimate fallback locale` at [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#use-localeconfig)).

Look at the languages that are available in your application. They are located in the `values/strings.xml`, `values-ru/strings.xml`, `values-fr/strings.xml`, etc. folders.

You need to specify the language that is in `values/strings.xml`. If it is English (usually it is), you should add `unqualifiedResLocale=en` or `unqualifiedResLocale=en-US` to the `resources.properties` file.